# No www folder is found in apache 2.2

Tags: php, apache2

I want to start learning php, I install apache 2.2 and I want to run my first.php file, I look for www folder in the installation folder of ApacheSoftwareFoundation but I couldn't find it.

here's the files in the apache[image]

I tried to put my php file in htdocs but it doesn't work , can some one help ?

**Edit**

Doesn't work means when I make http:localhost/first.php , returns **Unable to connect**

Now the apache is running, when I open htt'://localhost/
returns "it works"
but when I open any php file, it opens as-is ?!

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it doesn't work"? For example, does it show you the source/try to download the file? Does it get a 500 server error?

Comment: _Doesn't work_ means can you define?

Comment: Check the edit section please.

Comment: I run the httpd.exe as @Johann du Toit mention, but now the problem is the php code is not excuting.

Comment: what should I do with this error, when I run httpd.exe , cmd returns
httpd.exe couldn't reliably determine the  server's fully qualified domain name ???

Comment: @Alaa: this is just a warning that you can safely ignore. Best way to start/stop apache is to type `net start "apache2.2"` (lookup the exact service name in services control panel... type `start services.msc` on the windows command prompt.)

Comment: @salman, can u please check the edit part.

Comment: @Alaa: Finally I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now the apache is running, when I open
>   http://localhost/ returns "it works"
>   but when I open any php file, it opens
>   as-is ?!

A default installation of Apache on windows does not include the necessary modules to run PHP. After installing Apache, you must either:

1. Install PHP separately and follow the instructions [described here](http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/install-php-5-apache-windows.shtml) to configure Apache to use the installed version of PHP to serve .php files. I've been through this and took me hours to get every thing to work.
2. Recommended for you: uninstall Apache; install [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) instead.

Comment: @Alaa: the first error was "Unable to connect" which probably meant that Apache was not running. The "couldn't reliably determine the..." was a warning made by Apache. For _PHP errors that may occur_, you should check the php.ini file settings (you'll find the file somewhere with the WAMP directory). Set `display_errors = On` in that file.

Comment: I download WAMP, and everything works properly, many thanx 4 all :) .

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to check a couple of things...

- Make sure the Web Server is running ,either the service
  or the program, is running and that you have the correctly configured the Virtual Directories.
- If the web server just outputs the
  content of the .php file, it could
  mean that you don't have mod_php
  installed. Meaning the server does
  not have the Mime type registered so
  it will just try to treat it as a
  text file ...

And as your on windows you might consider using something like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html). It gives you a Full Working AMP (Apache Mysql Php) Stack with one install and a easy control manager to start/stop the servers. Other wise do a couple of Google searches on how to install the php module for your Web Server on Windows

**Update**

To start the server try executing the executable bin/httpd.exe .

Comment: I run the httpd.exe but when I refresh the page, the php code apprears on the browser ?!

Comment: That would mean you don't have the php module installed, the easiest solution would be to uninstall your web server and use XAMPP (in my post). Which will get your running in no time without worrying about modules etc.

Comment: yes XAMPP is probably the best solution, I would not recommend that the OP install PHP separately and wade through documentation to figure out how to make apache recognize PHP files.

Answer (score 0):

if you look in your httpd.conf file you will find the default root directory, it doesnt have to be called www. It is the htdocs by default.

error 500 covers a whole host of things. from compile error, to permissions.

Have you put a simple file of

```
<?php
echo "test";
?>
```

As your test php page to rule out other issues?

Comment: @Alaa: Ah, did you tell apache how it is supposed to run PHP?

Comment: @salman, what do u mean with telling appache how to run php??

Comment: @Alaa: an out of the box installation of apache will not understand or execute PHP scripts, it'll send php files to the browser as-is.

Comment: @Alaa, as Salaman A pointed out, by default apache has no understanding of php, you need to teach it. The php documentation explains exactly what you need to do

Comment: Once you tell it what to do about php, you will need to restart apache

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Construct your URI correctly: http://localhost/first.php (with the //)
2. Ensure that Apache is running

Answer (score 0):

all files in htdocs can be referenced from outside

Just put a basic file named index.php
and visit site http://localhost/

In general type in http://localhost/filename

Answer (score 0):

You say that you get a connection error when you try to go to your webpage. Since it looks like you're using Windows Vista or 7, make sure you're running Apache as an administrator; it can't bind to port 80 otherwise. Also check that other programs like Skype aren't binding to port 80. If you still can't find the problem, check the error log. (`logs/error.log` by default I think)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Apache was installed but not started

If you are using xampp start it and then start apache through control panel
for others look for similar instruction